# Found A Bug In Firebase Unity SDK, What Do I Do?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, fault

I upgraded from Firebase Unity SDK 4.4.1 to 5.2.0 and I believe I have found a bug when building to Android. I have posted about the bug in these forums, to see if anyone else can replicate, but I have no responses. I have sent emails to Firebase bug reporting, over a week ago, but I have heard nothing in response. I was about to launch a public beta with my app, it's finally almost finished, but this causes such a glaring bug that I fear, should I launch it regardless, most constructive feedback I would have otherwise received might instead go unreported in favor of telling me about this obvious bug (long sentence). What can I do from here? I'm at a loss as to what I can or should do from here?

Comment: File a bug error on your Github page?

Comment: My project isn't publicly on Github, if that's what you mean, so I don't think anyone would see it. Firebase used to have a Unity Github repo, but it's no longer updated, so I don't think anyone would see it there either. I'm not sure if I get your meaning. (but thanks for the reply!)

Comment: If you find a bug with a Firebase, you report the function. You don't need to upload your project. Just create new bug issue then explain it. If you want to make it easier to fix your bug then post a simple code that can replicate that bug while creating the bug report.